# List Groups Common to a set of Users

Tags: active-directory, users, groups

I need a way to find the set of groups common to a list of users.  I have a list of about 4 users I want to compare and find which groups they are all members of.  Is there a quick way to do this in Powershell or via LDAP queries?

Comment: For only 4 users why not open each user's properties side by side and see what groups they are in. It seems to me like you're looking for an overly complex solution to a simple problem.

Comment: Well they are in around 500 groups each.......I know I know its not ideal but its what it is.  Hand comparing over 500 groups each would most certainly not be a simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the 4 users to text files using `net user UserName /domain > out.txt` and then compare them using something like windiff.